# Design data structure

Tags: algorithms

3-13. Let A[1..n] be an array of real numbers. Design an algorithm to perform any sequence of the following operations:
Add(i,y) -- Add the value y to the ith number.
Partial-sum(i) -- Return the sum of the first i numbers, i.e. $\sum_{j=1}^j A[j]$

There are no insertions or deletions; the only change is to the values of the numbers. Each operation should take O(logn) steps. You may use one additional array of size n as a work space. ABove is an excercise from steve skiena. i am unable to solve this. Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Build a tree...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard easy-to-implement structure for this is called a Fenwick tree. It is very popular in programming competitions. [Here](http://petr-mitrichev.blogspot.ru/2013/05/fenwick-tree-range-updates.html) is a description on Petr Mitrichev's blog.

*UPDATE:* now that I look at it, Mitrichev's description may be too short. [Here](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees) is one that is more comprehensive.

Comment: The top coder explanation is missing some small details. It took some time for me to figure out but all is well. Thanks for the help.